# React: How to go about making a dark mode theme for a website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, darkmode

I was considering making a dark mode for a website I'm working on, and was wondering what was the optimal way to go about doing this. I have a react website and in the App.js file, I have routes to all the pages as well as a navbar. The navbar sits above the pages, and has a switch that allows the user to toggle between light and dark mode. Most of my components are made with material UI, and everything that is not using MUI is formatted in the App.css file.

I was wondering where I should put the switching between themes logic, and how I would pass the theme change down to my components. I've read that react contexts can be used, but I already have a context that wraps around  in index.js. Would I wrap that in another context in this case? Any help on how to structure this would be appreciated!